How to remove/stop the annoying spinner for 'Chat Notebook Settings'?
Somehow, I have started a forever spinning progress spinner, tool-tipped 'Chat Notebook Settings', in the top right corner of Mathematica 13.2 (on Ubuntu/PopOs). How do I remove or close it, or at least stop it from spinning continuously?

fig1. partial screenshot showing the entire toolbar. The annoying spinner is on the right, highlighted by a red box.
Though I don't intend to use any Chat services, I logged in anyway to see if that would make it stop - it doesn't. Disabling 'AllowChatServices' in Preferences, doesn't work either. It persists across restarts.
